# porque hace dos consultas en vez de una

Tags: python, mvc, xml, odoo

Estoy añadiendo un filtro de búsqueda para informes en el popup de odoo que cree y añadí algunas opciones de búsqueda genéricas y la finalidad es que partiendo del reporte general abstraiga cierta información depènde del filtro que se selecciones pero ahora lo que estoy haciendo es juntar dos filtros para muestre información muy especifica pero aa la hora de hacr la consulta en la interfaz de odoo me manda un error yo pense que no estaba entrnado a la funcion por lo cual s eme ocurrio poner un logger para ver el resultado y si hace la cunsulta pero tambien hace la consulta generica y quiere pegar ambos resultados en la tabla pero en la interfaz manda el error ya que en el xml donde estoy poniendo esos campo no tengo uno que en el general si y por eso me est amandando erro rcomo le puedo hacer para que solo me arroje una cosulta y no dos

Adjunto codigo:

```
import json
import io
from xlsxwriter import workbook
from datetime import date
from odoo.tools import date_utils
from odoo import fields, models, api
from odoo.exceptions import UserError, ValidationError
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)


class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
_name = "sale_report_general"

from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
to_date = fields.Date(string='Vencimiento')
type_transport = fields.Selection(
    [('c', 'Cotizaciones'), ('a', 'Aereo'), ('m', 'Maritmo'), ('t', 'Terrestre'), ('f', 'Ferias'),
     ('i', 'Importacion')], string='Tipo de cotizacion',default='c',required=True)
seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

def _get_data(self):
    sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('state', '!=', 'cancel')])
    validity_date = date.today()

    if self.from_date and self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() >= self.from_date and x.date_order.date() <= self.to_date,
                                  sale))
    elif not self.from_date and not self.to_date:
        sales_order = list(filter(lambda
                                      x: x.date_order.date() <= validity_date,
                                  sale))
    else:
        sales_order = sale

    logger.info('**********sales_order*** {0}****'.format(sales_order))

    result = []
    seller = []
    country = []
    for rec in self.seller_id:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        seller.append(a)
        logger.info('**********seller*** {0}****'.format(seller))
    for rec in self.country_arrival:
        a = {
            'id': rec,
            'name': rec.name
        }
        country.append(a)
        logger.info('**********country*** {0}****'.format(country))
    if self.type_transport == 'a' and self.seller_id:
        for rec in seller:
            for so in sales_order:
                if so.type_transport == 'aereo' and so.seller_id == rec['id']:
                    res = {
                        'name': so.name,
                        'date': so.date_order,
                        'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                        'consignee': so.consignee_id.name,
                        'freight': so.freight_type,
                        'gross': so.gross_weight,
                        'volume': so.volume,
                        'invoice': so.invoice_amount,
                        'country': so.country_arrival.name
                    }
                    result.append(res)
                    logger.info('********************************obtuvo el informe por empleado  y por tipo********{0}'.format(res))
```

ese es el filro que añadi esa funcio de `self.type_transport == 'a'` es una consulta generica para un tipo de cotización pero le añadi el `self.seller_id` para que busque un epleado en especifico y la finalidad es que me arroje cuantas cotizacines tiene en cierto empleado en especifico y eso lo plasme en un xml pero en la consola me manda que hace ambas la de este proceso y aparte la de la cotizacion y como en la cotizacion tengo un campo para identificar a los empleado y en el otro no porque esa informacion esta en el encabezado me esta mandando el error

Adjunto imagen de la terminal:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en el primer resultado es como si yo solo hubiera elegido el tipo de cotización y ahi es donde esta el error porque en ese filtro tengo el campo seller y en el de abajo que es el que yo necesito que me arroja de forma correcta el resultado pero sin el campo porque ese campo no lo necesito ahi y en el xml donde estoy mandando llamar esta informacion me quiere pegar ambas consutlas y no solo una y por eso me manda el error como puedo corregirlo

adjunto imagen del error y codigo xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ese es el erro que manda y esta es la parte del xml que estoy pintando la información:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
<template id="sales_general_view">
    <t t-call="web.html_container">
       <div class="header" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;">
           <h3 class="text-center">Sales General Report
              <span style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>From</strong>:<t t-esc="from_date"/> <strong>To</strong>: <t t-esc="to_date"/></span>
              <span style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>Tipo de cotizacion</strong>:<t t-esc="types"/></span>
              <span style="font-size: 14px;"><strong>Ejecutivo</strong>:<t t-esc="employee"/></span>
           </h3>
           <div class="article mt0 o_report_layout_standard">
               <t t-if="seller_id and type == 'a'">
                      <table class="table table-condensed table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <th style="with:30%">Date</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Folio</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Remitente</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Consignatario</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Volumen</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Peso_Bruto</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Factura</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Monto Fact</th>
                                <th class="text-center" style="width: 10%">Destino</th>
                             </thead>
                   <t t-foreach="form" t-as="exe">
                        <tr>
                             <td><span t-esc="exe['date']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['name']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['partner']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['consignee']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['volume']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['gross']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['freight']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['invoice']"/></td>
                             <td class="text-center"><span t-esc="exe['country']"/>></td>
                          </tr>
                   </t>
                   </table>
               </t
           </div>
           <div class="footer o_standard_footer" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
               <div class="row text-center">
                   <div class="col col-12 text-center">
                       <ul class="list-inline">
                           <li class="list-inline-item">Page:</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="page"/>
                           </li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">/</li>
                           <li class="list-inline-item">
                               <span class="topage"/>
                           </li>
                       </ul>
                   </div>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
   </t>
</template>
```

y aqui es donde va  a imprimir la consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

estás ejecutando dos consultas en lugar de una. La primera consulta es para obtener todas las órdenes de venta que no están canceladas y la segunda es para filtrar las órdenes de venta que cumplen con las condiciones especificadas en los campos de búsqueda de "from_date" y "to_date".

Para solucionarlo, en lugar de usar el método search() dos veces, puedes utilizar el método search() una sola vez y añadir todas las condiciones necesarias como argumentos en la lista de búsqueda. Por ejemplo, si quieres obtener solo las órdenes de venta que tienen una fecha de pedido entre "from_date" y "to_date" y que no están canceladas, puedes utilizar el siguiente código:

sale = self.env['sale.order'].search([('date_order', '>=', self.from_date), ('date_order', '<=', self.to_date), ('state', '!=', 'cancel')])

De esta manera, estarías realizando una sola consulta y obteniendo solo las órdenes de venta que cumplen con todas las condiciones especificadas. Además debes eliminar las lineas que utilizan el metodo filter() ya que estas hacen otra consulta con las ordenes previamente filtradas.

el código  "SaleReportAdvance" una vez refactorizado para realizar solo una consulta:

```
class SaleReportAdvance(models.TransientModel):
    _name = "sale_report_general"

    from_date = fields.Date(string="Fecha de cotizacion")
    to_date = fields.Date(string='Vencimiento')
    type_transport = fields.Selection(
        [('c', 'Cotizaciones'), ('a', 'Aereo'), ('m', 'Maritmo'), ('t', 'Terrestre'), ('f', 'Ferias'),
         ('i', 'Importacion')], string='Tipo de cotizacion',default='c',required=True)
    seller_id = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='hr.employee', string='Ejecutivo')
    country_arrival = fields.Many2many(comodel_name='res.country', string='Destino')

    def _get_data(self):
        search_domain = [('state', '!=', 'cancel')]
        if self.from_date:
            search_domain.append(('date_order', '>=', self.from_date))
        if self.to_date:
            search_domain.append(('date_order', '<=', self.to_date))
        if self.type_transport != 'c':
            search_domain.append(('type_transport', '=', self.type_transport))
        if self.seller_id:
            search_domain.append(('seller_id', 'in', self.seller_id.ids))
        if self.country_arrival:
            search_domain.append(('country_arrival', 'in', self.country_arrival.ids))

        sales_order = self.env['sale.order'].search(search_domain)
        
        seller = []
        country = []
        for rec in self.seller_id:
            a = {
                'id': rec,
                'name': rec.name
            }
            seller.append(a)
        for rec in self.country_arrival:
            a = {
                'id': rec,
                'name': rec.name
            }
            country.append(a)
        result = []
        for so in sales_order:
            res = {
                'name': so.name,
                'date': so.date_order,
                'partner': so.partner_id.name,
                ...
            }
            result.append(res)
        return result
```

aqui lo q t mostre se está utilizando el método search() una sola vez y se están añadiendo todas las condiciones necesarias como argumentos en la lista de búsqueda "search_domain". Además se ha eliminado el uso de filter() ya que estas hacen otra consulta con las ordenes previamente filtradas.También se ha eliminado el uso de la variable "validity_date" ya que esta no se utiliza en ninguna parte del código y se ha cambiado el tipo de transporte a ser una selección y no una busqueda con una fecha.

Es importante también mencionar que en la línea donde se añade el filtro de "seller_id", se está utilizando el método "ids" para obtener solo los ids de los ejecutivos seleccionados y no el objeto completo, y se esta utilizando el operador "in" para buscar en una lista de ids y no un objeto completo. Lo mismo aplica para el filtro de "country_arrival".

Comment: a ok entonces en el filtro que ocupo para el seller_id solo le tendria que agregar la s por lo que entendi y bueno de lo otro que pusiste arrriva si tengo duda porque por ejemplo ese de que la ocndicion es = a c ese es mi reporte general y del modelo que esta abstrayendo la informacion solo hay 5 registrso y esos si me los muestra y de ahi parti con las demas opciones snos e bien como se diga pero quiero concatenar o juntar esa de tipo a con el nombre del ejecutivo qu een este caso solo me deberia de cmostrar un solo registro y muetra ese registro mas aparte como si yo solo hubiera buscado a